# Cannot Connect Microsoft Dataverse to Microsoft Fabric

Tags: sql-server, powerapps, dataverse, power-platform, microsoft-fabric

I am working on an application prototype for my organisation to explore using Microsoft Fabric as a centralised database for all organisation data. My prototype involves creating a data table in a Lakehouse on MS Fabric containing volunteer details such as name, address, and area of interest in the organisation. A PowerApps application should accompany the prototype, this application should be used to add, edit, and delete volunteer records from the data table in MS Fabric.

I tried following the two guides below to link MS Fabric to MS Dataverse in order to access my Lakehouse table in a Power App:

1. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/maker/data-platform/azure-synapse-link-view-in-fabric
2. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/maker/data-platform/azure-synapse-link-build-apps-with-fabric

After following the first tutorial above, I managed to create a linked copy of all Dataverse tables in an MS Fabric Lakehouse. However, changes made to a table in MS Dataverse would not reflect in the MS Fabric linked table and vice versa.

I tried linking the volunteer details table from MS Fabric to Dataverse through a virtual table on the Power Platform page. Although I managed to create the linked table, attempting to edit this table on the MS Power Platform or in an MS Power Apps canvas app resulted in the following sets of errors. I also get the same errors if I try to connect a canvas app to the SQL server endpoint of the Fabric Lakehouse.

[image: Error in MS Power Platform]

[image: Error in MS Power App]

Thank you for the help in advance